# Powershell output file missing SamAccountName results

Tags: powershell

New to powershell, and I can't figure out why the SamAccountName column in the output file is empty. while the IsDisabled column has the account status results.

```
Import-Csv $filename | Foreach-Object{

    $user = ([ADSISEARCHER]"(samaccountname=$($_.SamAccountName))").FindOne()

    if($user)
    {
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
            IsDisabled = $user.GetDirectoryEntry().InvokeGet('AccountDisabled')
        }
    }
    else
    {
            Write-Warning "Can't find user '$($_.SamAccountName)'"
    }
} | Export-Csv $filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the 6th line to:

```
SamAccountName = $user.Properties.samaccountname
```

Comment: SamAccountName column is still empty.

Comment: Updated it with SamAccountName = $user.Properties.samaccountname and the SamAccountName column now has SystemDirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection as the result for every user. I also tried $user.Properties.SamAccountName and the result was blank again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify sAMAccountName as one of the properties to return. In addition you can specify the userAccountControl property and test the ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE bit to see if the user account is disabled. This will avoid the overhead of binding to each user object to test if disabled. Here is a short sample script:

```
param(
  [String[]] $sAMAccountName
)

$ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 2

$sAMAccountName | foreach-object {
  $searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(sAMAccountName=$($_))"
  $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("samaccountname","useraccountcontrol"))
  $result = $searcher.FindOne()
  if ( $result ) {
    $samName = $result.Properties["samaccountname"][0]
    $disabled = ($result.Properties["useraccountcontrol"][0] -band
      $ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE) -ne 0
    new-object PSObject -property @{
      "Name" = $samName
      "Disabled" = $disabled
    }
  } else {
    write-warning "Can't find user $_"
  }
}
```

Bill

Answer (score 0):

IIRC this is a known issue (bug) with case-sensitive ldap property names. To avoid that you can use the hashtable syntax and not worry about case:

```
$user.Properties['SAMACCOUNTNAME']
```